# What is the difference between мовити and говорити?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Is there any difference between *мовити* and *говорити*? I know in Russian that is one word, so got confused.

Comment: I have edited your question; *мовляти* denotes a repetitive/contiguous aspect, as the Russian suffix `-ива-` has. Please roll the edit back if you meant something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many quasi-synonymous verbs in Ukrainian that refer to the speaking process: *базікати*, *балакати*, *говорити*, *казати*, *мовити* (*мовляти*), *повідувати*, *повідомляти*, *ректи*, *розмовляти*, *спілкуватись*, *сповіщати*, *теревеніти*, etc.

*Говорити* is a general-purpose verb with relatively wide range of emphases:

- emphasis on the specific information being orally transferred (e.g. with direct object or with the *про* “about” preposition; optionally with addressee in dative);
- emphasis on the act of vocalization;
- emphasis on collaborative conversation (e.g. with subject is in plural or with the *з* “with” preposition);
- emphasis on ability of speaking (e.g. with negation or with some language/mode specification);
- can refer to non-oral information transfer and be used in figurative meanings.

*Мовити* (*мовляти*) has much narrower set of meanings: it usually emphasizes the information being transferred and therefore usually is accompanied by direct object or the *про* preposition. Also (even in it's proper meaning) it's probably less used than *говорити*, it's probably more a book-style word. (Also in mass media it's sometimes used to denote the process of broadcasting (often without direct object and without *про* preposition), but for me it sounds a bit artificial, like an attempt to bring a new meaning to an old word.)

BTW, Russian has direct equivalent of Ukrainian *мовити* — *молвить*. But while Ukrainian *мовити* is just a bit outdated (more rare and more book-style than *говорити*, but still usable), Russian *молвить* is fully archaic and never used in real life.